# JAX-RS + JAXB (XML) -- How to pass single byte as hexadecimal?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, hex, jax-rs

To pass a byte array as hexadecimal we can use:

```
@XmlElement
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(HexBinaryAdapter.class)
private byte[] data;
```

How can we transfer a single byte formatted as hexadecimal? With the following code it does not work. When I try to read it like this I get: `HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error`.

```
@XmlAttribute
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(HexBinaryAdapter.class)
private byte id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

**XmlAdapter (ByteAdapter)**

You could create your own `XmlAdapter` that converts between a `Byte` and the desired hexBinary `String`.

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class ByteAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Byte> {

    @Override
    public Byte unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(v)[0];
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Byte v) throws Exception {
        return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(new byte[] {v});
    }

}
```

**Domain Model**

For the `XmlAdapter` to work across all [JAXB (JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementations it will need to be placed on a field/property of type `Byte` and not `byte`.  In this example we will make the field `Byte` and leverage field access with JAXB keeping the property of type `byte`.  We will leverage the `@XmlSchemaType` annotation to specify that the corresponding schema type is `hexBinary`.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ByteAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name="hexBinary")
    public Byte bar;

    public byte getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(byte bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

Below is some code you can run to prove that everything works.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum17483278/input.xml");
        Foo foo = (Foo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
    <bar>2B</bar>
</foo>
```